# .Net Core Implementing Redis cashing with master and slave connections

Tags: redis, asp.net-core

I need to use **redis connection with Master and Slave configuration in dot net core**.

Below code is configured to get the primary server(Master) which is configured to port 6379, and I have a slave configured to 6380.

```
services.AddSingleton < IDistributedCache > (serviceProvider =>
 new RedisCache(new RedisCacheOptions {
    Configuration = primaryServer.ConnectionString,
    InstanceName = primaryServer.InstanceName
 }));
```

Below is the configuration:

```
"RedisSettings": {
  "PrimaryServer": {
    "ConnectionString": "127.0.0.1:6379",
      "InstanceName": "SomeName"
  },
    "SecondaryServer": {
      "ConnectionString": "127.0.0.1:6380",
        "InstanceName": "SomeName"
    }
}
```

Let me know if it is possible to have a master and slave setup for **IDistributedCache**

Comment: @h.salman, I have installed "Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis": "1.0.0"